# Issue with stack allocator with embedded arena

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, allocator

I'm experiencing crashes when using Howard Hinnant's [stack-based allocator](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.h), both on 
MacOS with and on 64-bit Linux with Clang 3.4. Here is a minimal example
triggering the crash in the destructor of the container:

```
#include <vector>
#include "stack_alloc.h"

template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, size_t N>
using stack_container = C<T, stack_alloc<T, N>>;

using stack_vector = stack_container<std::vector, size_t, 4>;

int main()
{
  auto s = stack_vector{1, 2, 3};
  auto m = std::move(s);
}
```

Compiled as follows:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -Wall crash.cc && ./a.out
```

Do you have any ideas why this crash would happen? I've also tried 
reimplemented `stack_alloc` in terms of the arena implementation from
[short_alloc](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h), but I still get the crash when moving a stack-based container.

Here is a Linux backtrace:

```
#0  _int_free (av=0x394f5b8760 <main_arena>, p=0x7fffffffe0f0, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3901
#1  0x00000000004013eb in stack_alloc<unsigned long, 4ul>::deallocate (this=0x7fffffffe080, p=0x7fffffffe100, n=3)
    at ./stack_alloc.h:71
#2  0x0000000000401343 in capacity (this=0x7fffffffe060, this=0x7fffffffe060, __a=..., __p=0x7fffffffe100, __n=3)
    at .../include/c++/v1/memory:1443
#3  std::__1::__vector_base<unsigned long, stack_alloc<unsigned long, 4> >::~__vector_base (this=0x7fffffffe060)
    at .../include/c++/v1/vector:476
#4  0x0000000000400fa5 in std::__1::vector<unsigned long, stack_alloc<unsigned long, 4> >::~vector (this=0x7fffffffe060)
    at .../include/c++/v1/vector:481
#5  0x0000000000400f6e in main () at crash.cc:13
```

I'd be interested *(i)* if folks can reproduce the error, and *(ii)* how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you move-construct the second container, the container move-constructs the allocator and takes over the pointers. When the second container dies, the it tries to deallocate the pointers and does it wrongly, causing UB in the pointer comparison in `deallocate()`.

The "allocator" does not satisfy the allocator requirements, particularly:

> `X a1(move(a))` Post: `a1` equals the prior value of `a`.

Two allocators are "equal" if one can deallocate memory allocated by the other, which is blatantly not the case here.

Comment: Another way of seeing this is that an allocator's state can never be the allocator's object identity itself.

Comment: Interesting, so this bug boils down to the notion of allocator equality. But if an allocator contains it's own memory, then by definition two different instances can never be equal. This makes me wonder what is the right solution? Does it suffice to implement `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` (and `*_copy_*`) to indicate that two distinct contains should always use their own allocator?

Answer (score 4):

You are using the non-conforming C++11 `stack_alloc`. As Hinnant [himself wrote](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html),

> I've updated this article with a new allocator that is fully C++11
>   conforming. The allocator it replaces was not fully C++03 nor C++11
>   conforming because copies were not equal.

The corrected version is named `short_alloc` and is [found here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h).

Usage requires **placing the stack buffer outside the allocator** (using [Hinnant's notation](http://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html)):

```
int main()
{
  arena<N> a; // change N to required space
  auto s = SmallVector({1, 2, 3}, Alloc{a});
  auto m = std::move(s);
}
```

Comment: Ack. This is the standard notion of an "arena allocator" (e.g. [see here](https://rawgit.com/google/cxx-std-draft/allocator-paper/allocator_example_usage.html) with a user-supplied arena.

Comment: I understand that the "old" `stack_alloc` is not standard-conforming, and in this case the move operation causes UB. While `short_alloc` fixes the issue, the reason why I went with `stack_alloc` is the interface: it's a *transparent* drop-in replacement that does not require any user code changes. With `short_alloc`, I need to add new code for arena bookkeeping, which I was trying to avoid. Is it possible to create an allocator which could be used in the above sketched `stack_container<C, T, N>` style?interface?

Comment: @MatthiasVallentin no that was exactly the point of the Hinnant quote: the old version was cleaner at the call site, but it was not conforming to the C++11 Standard because copies were not equal. There is no way around that short from writing your own allocator proposal to make that legal :-) But I feel your pain (I use the short_alloc a lot and it hurts my eyes, especially because for performance you also need to do a `v.reserve(N / sizeof(T))` in order to claim the entire arena).

Comment: @TemplateRex: Right on. You just can't have a completely invisible automatic storage. That said, I think that an automatic arena variable is entirely appropriate, manageable and reasonable for those few situations where that kind of memory locality is desirable. The next best thing would be a "small size optimized" vector with a configurable amount of internal storage; like `basic_string` but larger, and foregoing the iterator swap guarantees. Chances are you won't want both at the same time.