# short_alloc with _GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING disabled

Tags: c++

I wonder if anyone has run [Howard Hinnant's short_alloc](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html) when libglibc++ has `_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING=1`. I am stuck on how to workaround this error:

```cpp
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.tcc:596:30: error: no matching function for call to 'myapp::short_alloc<char, 131072>::short_alloc()'
  596 |       if (__n == 0 && __a == _Alloc())
      |                              ^~~~~~~~
```

https://godbolt.org/z/z79K584EE

Comment: Works fine for me: https://godbolt.org/z/f3qc89hev; Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @user17732522 Sorry, my bad. `D_GLIBCXX_FULLY_DYNAMIC_STRING` should be disabled. See my example in the post. Thank you.

Comment: This is all pre C++17. I think you could nowadays use pmr allocators for this.

Comment: @user17732522 sorry, forgot you need to pass the allocator to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of this allocator is to use stack memory. `arena_type` is used to reserve some stack memory for the allocator.

The allocator instance needs to know which arena to use. Therefore you cannot default-construct the allocator and by extension the string.

You always need to provide a reference to the arena to use when constructing a new string, e.g.:

```
using alloc = short_alloc<char, 1024, alignof(char)>;
using mystring = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, alloc>;

alloc::arena_type a;
mystring str(a);
str = "Hello world!";

std::cout << str;
```

---

If you are wondering why it is necessary to define the area variable separately, rather than it just being a part of the allocator object: This is because it is not possible to do the latter and get an allocator conforming to the standard requirements for an allocator. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193969/issue-with-stack-allocator-with-embedded-arena).